# Grey Blocks in background image

Tags: html, css

I have set a background image on my website, in some browsers there come grey blocks in the background image. How do I solve this?

Website: http://haptotherapiemris.nl/

Here is my Css code:

```
.main {
margin: 0 auto;
background: transparent url(http://dansolution.nl/klanten/background/bg.jpg) repeat-y                center top;
width: 1000px;
min-height: 1000px;
text-align: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Please specify what browsers exactly and post screenshot of the bad behavior.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the grey color to the right and left of your bg image... then you can remove it from the body { css file.

```
body {background-color:#595959; ...... }
```

to be

```
body {background-color:#ffffff; ..... }
```